# What's about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}f(X^{\frac{1}{n}})$, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, absolute-convergence, mobius-function, analytic-functions

Let $X=\sigma+it$ the **complex variable**, and $\mu(n)$ the **Möbius function**.

Inspired in **Riemann function** $R(X)$ I would like to ask you

> **Question.** What conditions are required to be satisfied by a function $f(X)$ with the purpose to presume that $$F(X):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}f(X^{\frac{1}{n}})$$ is well defined? I say conditions for good functions (an ample set of complex functions for which is easy answer the question, for a half-plane of convergence). **Thanks in advance.**

I know that Riemann function $R(X)$ is **smooth**, then if you want to provide us conditions for which $F(X)$ be diffentiable in the complex sense, you are welcome. I know that it it possible write $$|F(X)|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|f(X^{\frac{1}{n}})|}{n},$$
and that could be useful define $F(X)$ as $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{n}f(X^{\frac{1}{n}})$, but I have no idea to solve and deduce where is defined $F(X)$.

Please if there are inaccurancies in my questions add a comment to improve this post.

Comment: I add this bounty as a **question is widely applicable to a large audience**, because I believe that it is interesting, because we know in the university Taylor or Fourier expansions, but not about previous kind of expansion. I know that there examples in the literature of use of such series, and the approximation in such example is better than using Fourier series. Of course this is difficult to understand to me currently, but I believe that it is interesting, also what is the error when one takes only a finite number of terms of previous series if one knows the identity with respect $F(X)$.

Comment: If $X$ is a complex variable, then is $f(X^{1/n})$ using the principal $n$th root? And when you say half-plane of convergence, you mean $F$ should be defined on a half-plane -- any half-plane?

Comment: Truly I don't know how answer your questions rigurously, but I can accept the use of the principal branch for the nth root, and accept that F will be defined in its corresponding half-plane. Also I will accept and I'll be glad if someone can/want to do a call to other user/moderator to know if my question has mathematical meaning at 100 %. Many thanks @6005

Comment: All users, maybe it is neccesary state the main branch of the logarithm to work. I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** If $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, $f(1) = 0$, and $\text{Log}$ is your favorite branch of the complex logarithm, then, defining $X^{1/n} = e^{(\text{Log} X)/n}$, $F$ is defined except at the branch of the complex logarithm where $\text{Log}$ was undefined. In fact, $F$ is holomorphic on this region.

To state this a little more cleanly, let me instead consider the functions $G(Y) = F(e^Y)$ and $g(y) = f(e^y)$, so that
$$
G(Y)
  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}f((e^Y)^{\frac{1}{n}})
  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}g\left(\frac{Y}{n}\right).
$$
If $f(1) = 0$, then $g(0) = 0$.
Below, I will show that given this, if $g$ is holomorphic in an open disc of radius $R$ around $0$, then so is $G$. We may then recover a (not unique) definition for $F$ by picking a branch of the complex logarithm $\text{Log}$ as described above, thus giving a unique definition to $X^{(1/n)}$ and letting us recover $F$ by the formula $F(x) = G(\text{Log}(x))$.

$F$ will thus be holomorphic on the set of $x$ such that $\text{Log}(x)$ lies in the domain of $G$, i.e. the set of $x$ such that $|\text{Log}(x)| < R$.

In particular, to justify my first sentence, if $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, then $g$ is holomorphic everywhere, so $G$ is holomorphic everywhere, so $F$ is holomorphic on the domain of $\text{Log}$.

---

**Details:**
It remains to prove the statement above, that is that assuming $g(0) = 0$, if $g$ is holomorphic in an open disc of radius $R \ge 0$ around $0$, then $G$ is defined and also holomorphic in that open disc. We specifically allow for $R = \infty$.

Note that $g(Y/n)$ is holomorphic for $|Y| < R$, for each $n$. So we have an infinite sum of holomorphic functions in this disc. Referring to Soarer's comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52843/when-do-series-converge-to-meromorphic-functions-on-mathbbc):

> [an] infinite sum of holomorphic functions (on a domain) that converge uniformly on every compact subset is holomorphic

we just need to show that series for $G(Y)$ converges uniformly on the set $|Y| \le r$, for any finite radius $r < R$ (again this allows for $R = \infty$). It suffices to bound the tail end of the series uniformly and with a bound that goes to $0$. So let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $|Y| \le r$.
Expand $g$ as a power series around $0$ as
$$
g(z) = \sum_{i \ge 1} a_i \frac{z^i}{i!}
$$
with $i \ge 1$ since $g(0) = 0$.
Note that $g$ converges absolutely for $|z| \le r$, so that we may define a finite constant $M_r = \sum_{i \ge 1} |a_i| \frac{r^i}{i!}$.
Now we have
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}g\left(\tfrac{Y}{n}\right)\right|
&\le \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \left| g\left(\tfrac{Y}{n}\right)\right| \\
&= \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \left| \sum_{i = 1}^\infty a_i \frac{(Y/n)^i}{i!}\right| \\
&\le \sum_{n=N}^\infty \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{i+1} i!} |a_i| |Y|^i \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^\infty |a_i| \frac{|Y|^i}{i!} \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{i+1}} \\
&\le \sum_{i = 1}^\infty |a_i| \frac{|Y|^i}{i!} \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \\
&= \left( \sum_{i = 1}^\infty |a_i| \frac{|Y|^i}{i!} \right)
\left( \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \right) \\
&\le M_r \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2},
\end{align*}
which approaches $0$ as $N \to \infty$ since the series for $\zeta(2)$ converges.

Therefore, the series converges uniformly on any closed discs $|z| \le r$. Thus it converges uniformly on all compact subsets of $|z| < R$, and so the sum of these infinitely many holomorphic functions is holomorphic. So $G$ is holomorphic on $|z| < R$.

Comment: Your answer is very detaled, now I need to read carefuly to understand your reasoning, and ask you if I need some explanation. Many thanks.

Comment: @user243301 No problem :) Please do ask if you get stuck on anything. There's some chance there's an error somewhere in there.

Comment: Very thanks much for your detailed answer, now is a reference for me to study it more, and provide myself different examples.